# How to select only rows having max value, but maintaining date timeline

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have this table:

| id | price | sold_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 30 | 2022-01-04 |
| 3 | 15 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 30 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-01-01 |

And I want to aggregate the price column, but only the consecutive values in the `solt_at` timeline. I want to select the latest one.

| id | price | sold_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 30 | 2022-01-04 |
| 3 | 15 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 30 | 2022-01-02 |

Please note that the two rows with `30` price stay since they have another price in between. I tried `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` but couldn't find the exact way to do that. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as well

Comment: you can do it with lag window function

Comment: Thank you so much folks, I could solve it with the associated post. Appreciate it!!!